# Размещение текста на картинке, не допуская его смещения на различных экранах

Tags: android, android-layout

Как задать положение TextView в определенном месте ImageView? Предполагаю, что буду использовать Relativelayout. Должно быть много TextView и если использовать только отступы, думаю на некоторых экранах будет ползти. Или я не прав? Может быть есть варианты получше?
Вот как может выглядеть это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нарисуйте. Не понятно, о чем вы.

Comment: FrameLayout, VectorDrawable, либо самому рисовать на канвасе?

Comment: Изменил изображения для понятности. Если самому рисовать, не думаю что будет лучше чем в Relativelayout, так же нужно будет много отступов устанавливать для всех разрешений.но главное думаю текст будет ползи. По поводу FrameLayout, VectorDrawable не сильно понятно как. Пример бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом: разбил изображение сначала на вертикальные LinearLayout,  layout_weiht которых был пропорционально равен их знаниям в пикселях. После, для каждой view внутри я сделал тоже самое. Решение не самое лучшее, так как вложенные веса не рекомендуется использовать, но цели я достиг, все TextView будут на своих местах. Вот как приблизительно выглядит разметка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]